# Use color intensities instead of bubble size for weighted scatter plot

Tags: python, r, seaborn, stata, scatter-plot

Is there any way that we can use color intensities instead of bubble size for a weighted scatter plot? I have been searching for solutions online for hours, but I still did not find one. I use the following Penguins data for illustration.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

penguins_data="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datavizpyr/data/master/palmer_penguin_species.tsv"
penguins_df = pd.read_csv(penguins_data, sep="\t")

sns.set_context("talk", font_scale=1.1)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.scatterplot(x="culmen_length_mm", 
                y="culmen_depth_mm",
                size="body_mass_g",
                sizes=(20,500),
                alpha=0.5,
                data=penguins_df)
# Put the legend out of the figure
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1),borderaxespad=0)
# Put the legend out of the figure
#plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.54),  borderaxespad=0.)
plt.xlabel("Culmen Length (mm)")
plt.ylabel("Culmen Depth (mm)")
plt.title("Bubble plot in Seaborn")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("Bubble_plot_size_range_Seaborn_scatterplot.png",
                    format='png',dpi=150)
```

The bubble plot with the smallest bubble corresponding to the smallest body mass and the biggest bubble corresponds to the largest body mass. However, I need the color intensity for the weighted scatter plot. For example, a darker color indicates that it occurs more frequently, and a lighter color indicates that it occurs less frequently. Any suggestion using Stata (preferred), Python, or R is highly appreciated.

I found something in Stata like this [one](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1538359-scatterplots-with-weighted-marker-size-revisited), but my data structure is completely different, so it does not work out.

Comment: "a darker color indicates that it occurs more frequently, and a lighter color indicates that it occurs less frequently" However, you are plotting measured variables, so I don't understand where frequency comes from.

Comment: @NickCox Maybe I did not use the right data to illustrate. I have x and y categorical variables. In Stata, normally we can generate group identifiers by using "egen weight_xy = group(x y)", then "twoway scatter y x [weight = weight_xy]". However, I would like to use color intensities instead of bubble size for a weighted scatter plot. Since you are an active Stata user, do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: To get different colours, you need several _y_ variables plotted against another _x_ variable. A method using `separate` is mentioned in the thread you cite and its links. There isn't a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a new column in your dataframe for the color, where you adjust the alpha channel by yourself?

After that you can probably work from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389331/adjust-different-transparency-for-different-class-in-seaborn-scatter-plot) to use it as the color column as the hue for the markers.

Comment: thanks, but I think hue is only for grouping variable that will produce points with different colors. It has nothing to do with weight, unfortunately.

Comment: @Arthur, welcome to StackOverflow! Since your answer doesn't directly answer the OP question (your answer is indeed another question together with a suggested link), it is more suitable to be posted as a comment instead of an answer.  Further information (can be found here)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer] :)